# Octez Node: No Validation Plugin found for Protocols Edo Onwards

Tags: node, octez, validation

I am encountering a strange problem  with the Tezos node as published in the Opam repository, wherein the node begins to spew no validation plugins found for protocols Edo and onwards. Peculiarly, the node still seems to chug along and process blocks (I would anticipate that to be a fatal error, unless things work differently than how I am imagining them). Is this a failure in my installation method or something that hasn't been fixed yet? I installed Octez by way of opam install octez, and did notice that some of the Rust wasm things failed to install, namely the debugger, but I don't think that is related. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Please include the exact error messages that you get. In particular, there were two versions of the Edo protocol (PtEdoTez and PtEdo2Zk) and knowing which one is reported as missing may be useful.

Comment: 2024-01-08T02:16:06.828-00:00 [block.validation.validation_plugin_not_found] no validation plugin found for protocol PtEdo2ZkT9oKpimTah6x2embF25oss54njMuPzkJTEi5RqfdZFA

Answer (score 0):

Validation plugins for old protocols are no longer present in new versions of octez, because there is no longer any need to validate the content of a mempool against an old proto. Full blocks, on the other hand, are still being validated, so catching up remains possible.